# moses train-model.perl script error, --lm factor:order:filename requied

Tags: nlp, machine-translation, moses

when I run:

```
$MOSES/scripts/training/train-model.perl -hierarchical -ghkm -external-bin-dir /home/zhanwang/giza-pp/tools/ -root-dir . --corpus corpus/nl2mr --f mr --e nl
```

showed:

> ERROR: use --lm factor:order:filename to specify at least one language
>   model at /home/zhanwang/mosesdecoder/scripts/training/train-model.perl
>   line 597.
>
> root@zhanwang-virtual-machine:/home/zhanwang/mosesmodel/corpus3#
>   $MOSES/scripts/training/train-model.perl

But I don't want to use factor model.

try this too, show me the same thing. whatever parameter I try ,it just ask me to use --`lm factor:order:filename`.

For an standard phrase model, you will typically run the training script as follows.

```
 train-model.perl -root-dir . --corpus corpus/euro --f de --e en
```

I want to build syntax-base translation model, what should I do?

```
$MOSES/scripts/training/train-model.perl -ghkm -external-bin-dir /home/zhanwang/giza-pp/tools/ -root-dir . --corpus corpus/nl2mr --f mr --e nl
```

here is my corpus:

```
root@zhanwang-virtual-machine:/home/zhanwang/mosesmodel/corpus3/corpus# head nl2mr.nl nl2mr.mr

==> nl2mr.nl <==

Give me the cities in Virginia .

What are the high points of states surrounding Mississippi ?

==> nl2mr.mr <==

answer city loc_2 stateid 'virginia'

answer high_point_1 state next_to_2 stateid 'mississippi'
```

I want to extract ghkm rules and build a model that can translate "Give me the cities in Virginia ." to "answer city loc_2 stateid 'virginia'"

Comment: Did you read the guide from moses' web page? For syntax-based http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.SyntaxTutorial#ntoc15